# How to pick an image from gallery in samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to build an app can choose photo from the gallery. this is the code i use

```
Intent photo_pick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photo_pick.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photo_pick , PICK_PHOTO_INTENT );
```

this code i had try and it work on XiaoMi, Huawei phone. But when it work on samsung the path it return is the error path cannot to get the photo.

How to improve it to let the samsung phone also can work?

Comment: `the path it return is the error path`.??? Please give an example of such a 'path'. Show your code so we can see what you mean by 'path'.

Comment: the path return > "content://media/external/images/media/24" but the correct path should return like this "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2017-04-06-01-45-03.png"

Comment: You get a content scheme path but you want a file system path. There is no reason to want that. Try to live with the content scheme. Modern times are here You can do all with it. You did not tell why you think you need a file system path. You dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below code for choose photo from the gallery,

```
private static final int REQUEST_PROFILE_ALBUM = 1;


Intent int_album = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
int_album.setType("image/*");
int_album.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, img_url);
startActivityForResult(int_album, REQUEST_PROFILE_ALBUM);
```

After Select Image onActivityResult is called,

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PROFILE_ALBUM && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may helps you:

```
Button btn_selectimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_selectimage);

btn_selectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                img_capture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Code for xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_selectimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Picture"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Bring up gallery to select a photo
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
       }else{
            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this,"No Gallery app found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a image like this

```
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Once you pick a image  **onActivityResult** is called automatically

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this is same with the code i using and this doesn't work in samsung rom

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute below code, you will require to get request persmission only if android version is higher then lolipop

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 500);
```